# "Божественное провидение" - что с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Найдено:

*Божественное Провидение* и *Божественное провидение*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Из словаря:**

Провидение, -я (о Боге); но: **Божественное провидение**

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=провидение&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x)

Но это скорее в высоком смысле, в религиозной литературе.

2) В Нацкорпусе чаще пишут ***божественное провидение***:

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C1%EE%E6%E5%F1%F2%E2%E5%ED%ED%EE%E5%20%EF%F0%EE%E2%E8%E4%E5%ED%E8%E5&p=0

...инициатива в романе передается случаю, управляющему одновременностью и разновременностью явлений или как безличная, не названная в романе сила, или как судьба, **или как божественное провидение**...[М. М. Бахтин. Формы времени и хронотопа в романе (1937-1938)]